# ROR grouped_options_for_select dynamic populate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code

in view

`grouped_options_for_select(@grouped_options, nil, @options_1)`

in controller

```
@options_1 = [africa]
```

`@grouped_options = [['North America',[['United States','US'],'Canada']],
             ['Europe',['Denmark','Germany','France']]]`

---

how to make the countries populate dynamically from an array an not type them one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for those who might be interested...
this what i did

in view

```
options_for_select(@options, :disabled => ['North America', 'Europe']
```

in controller

```
@countries.each do |l|
    @options << [l.name, l.id]
  end
```

for this output

Africa

 North America

      United States, US

     Canada

Europe

     Denmark

     Germany

     France